# Get another object while LINQ executing

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know how to explain this clearly. But I am trying to get another properties while LINQ statement is executing.
 example:

This is a working LINQ Statement:

```
if (customerData.Demographics.Count > 0)
{
    string[] communities = {"ONLINE_TECH_COMM", "ONLINE_PROF_NET", "ONLINE_TECH_SECTIONS"};
    var results = (from CustomerDemographic customerDemographic in customerData.Demographics where (customerDemographic.UserD2==DateTime.MinValue)
           select new Models.MemberOnlineCommunityPreferences()
           {
               DemographicCode = customerDemographic.DemographicCodeString,
               DemographicSubCode = customerDemographic.DemographicSubcodeString,
     }).Where(x=>communities.Contains(x.DemographicCode)).OrderBy(x=>x.DemographicCode).ToList();
```

Now, I need to pass `DemographicCodeString` and `DemographicSubcodeString` values to

```
oApplicationSubcode = TIMSS.API.CachedApplicationData.ApplicationDataCache.get_ApplicationSubCode("CUS", "DEMOGRAPHIC", DemographicCodeString, DemographicSubcodeString);
```

And, check properties `WebEnabled =="Y"` and `Active=="Y"`, then only read `customerData` and assign it to results. Is it possible to do this with LINQ in a single statement?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, `WebEnabled` and `Active` are properties from `oApplicationSubcode`, and you need to check whether they are `Y` for each `MemberOnlineCommunityPreferences` object? If this is true, I suppose you could include the method call `get_ApplicationSubCode` from inside the where clause and filter right there?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the "let" keyword.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx

```
var results = from CustomerDemographic customerDemographic in customerData.Demographics

let code = customerDemographic.DemographicCodeString

let subcode = customerDemographic.DemographicSubcodeString

where communities.Contains(code) && customerDemographic.UserD2==DateTime.MinValue

let appSubCode = TIMSS.API.CachedApplicationData.ApplicationDataCache.get_ApplicationSubCode("CUS", "DEMOGRAPHIC", code, subcode)

where appSubCode.WebEnabled =="Y" && appSubCode.Active=="Y"

select new Models.MemberOnlineCommunityPreferences()
       {
           DemographicCode = code,
           DemographicSubCode = subcode
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (completely untested)?

```
var results = (from CustomerDemographic customerDemographic in customerData.Demographics
               where (customerDemographic.UserD2==DateTime.MinValue)
                  && communities.Contains(x.DemographicCodeString)
               let applicationSubcode = TIMSS.API.CachedApplicationData.ApplicationDataCache.get_ApplicationSubCode("CUS", "DEMOGRAPHIC", customerDemographic.DemographicCodeString, customerDemographic.DemographicSubcodeString)
               where applicationSubcode.WebEnabled == "Y"
                  && applicationSubcode.Active == "Y"
               orderby customerDemographic.DemographicCodeString
               select customerDemographic).ToList();
```